# How to get figure counter to follow theorem counter?

Tags: floats, numbering

I am trying to get my figure to counter to follow my theorem counter. I created a few different environments: lemma, example, definitions, etc. I have gotten all of them to follow my theorem counter.

The numbering goes Chapter.Section.theorem. So it will go like this:

> Chapter 2 "The Second Chapter"
>
> Section 2.1 The First Section
>
> Definition 2.1.1 - First Definition
>
> Theorem 2.1.2 - The First Theorem
>
> Section 2.2 The Second Section
>
> Chapter 3 "The Third Chapter"

etc...

However, the figures don't seem to follow the counter. The first figure (in section 2.4) is number Figure 2.3 ... So I'm trying to get it to fall in line with the rest so that it would look like:

Example 3.2.5 - The Example

Figure 3.2.6 - The Figure for Example 3.2.5

Any suggestions? I put all the code that I think is applicable below. Let me know if you need more/something else...

```
\documentclass{thesis} %This is my school's self-made document class

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}   %Added by me
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

%\makeatletter  %Added by me
%\let\c@theorem\c@figure
%\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{The Figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I've attempted the `\let\c@theorem\c@figure` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Figures are _always_ numbered independently from theorem-like environments. Do you really want to change this standard?

Comment: Moreover, figures are floats, while theorems are not. So, you may end up with a different order in terms of the numbering and the actual placement of content on the page.

Comment: The only way is to get around the issue Werner stated is drop the floating feature of figure

Comment: @tohecz Well, if figures are _always_ numbered independently, then maybe I don't want to change that standard. Although I do like the fact that everything in my paper is enumerated and can be found based on the number of the current object. So if I reference a figure, I know exactly where it can be found. I've found that this simplifies everything greatly! Why doesn't _everyone_ do that??

Comment: @tohecz Additionally, the standard way of doing it seems to give two different figures the same call number. I have two Figure 2.4's in my paper (in two different sections: one in 2.4 and one in 2.7 ... I assume this is incorrect and _not_ standard, right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proposition:

1. Don't use floating figures, remove `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` around the graphics and caption
2. Use `caption` package and `\captionof{figure}{foo text}` instead of standard `\caption` command
3. Redefine the figure output command `\thefigure` to obtain the `\thetheorem.\arabic{figure}` output
4. (Optional) Use a resetting of figure counter by theorem, i.e. `@addtoreset{figure}{theorem}` If this is not wanted, just comment that line

---

```
\documentclass{book} % can't use thesis.cls here, since unknown!!!

\usepackage{caption}%
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}   %Added by me
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

%\makeatletter  %Added by me
%\let\c@theorem\c@figure
%\makeatother

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{figure}{theorem}
\makeatother

\let\StandardTheFigure\thefigure
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thetheorem.\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My first chapter}

\section{The very first section}%

\begin{theorem}
\( E = m c^2 \)
\end{theorem}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{somefig}
\captionof{figure}{The Figure}
\end{center}

\begin{theorem}
\( E^2 = p^2 c^2 + \left({m c^2}\right)^2 \)
\end{theorem}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{somefig}
\captionof{figure}{Another figure}%
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my gosh! Wonderful. Thank you! Additionally, is there any way to get the above to be Theorem 1.1.1, Figure 1.1.2, Theorem 1.1.3, Figure 1.1.4, etc... ?

Comment: @BarkJr.Sure, just comment out `@\addtoreset{figure}{theorem}` or delete that line completely. The figure number will be reset then per chapter or per section, that depends on the class settings

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same thing and the answer is a bit simpler I think. With my Method it doesn't matter if you use the figure environment or not.

1. You need to overwrite of the figure Counter to be a theorem counter:
   `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{theorem}}`
2. you need to raise the theorem counter by one before you use captionof or caption:
   `\stepcounter{theorem}` or `\addtocounter{theorem}{1}` \

\thefigure is calling on the figure counter and you basically overwrite the counter. \thesection is there for the 1.1, because the theorem counter is also displayed that way, and the \arabic{theorem} ist just printing the theorem counter. if you use a \begin{theorem} the counter automatically raises itself but it doesn't with figures, when you just call upon it, that's why you have to raise it yourself, when you use a figure. so in total:

```
\documentclass{book} % can't use thesis.cls here, since unknown!!!

\usepackage{caption}%
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}   %Added by me
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{theorem}}%IMPORTANT

\begin{document}

\chapter{My first chapter}

\section{The very first section}%

\begin{theorem}
\( E = m c^2 \)
\end{theorem}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\stepcounter{theorem}%IMPORTANT
\includegraphics{somefig}
\caption{The Figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{theorem}
\( E^2 = p^2 c^2 + \left({m c^2}\right)^2 \)
\end{theorem}

\begin{center}
\stepcounter{theorem}%IMPORTANT
\includegraphics{somefig}
\captionof{figure}{Another figure}%
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image]